# Why doesn't `npm search react` match `react-native`?

Tags: react-native, npm, command-line

I ran the following command to try searching the `react-native` package:

```
npm search react
```

However, I don't see `react-native` in the list of results.

I tried accessing the sub-command documentation by running

```
npm help search
```

which reads:

> Search the registry for packages matching the search terms. npm search performs a linear, incremental, lexically-ordered search through package metadata for all files in the registry. If color is enabled, it will further highlight the matches in the results.

So, I understand that running

```
npm search react
```

should list `react-native` as one of the results. I read through the entire help page above, but couldn't find any option that I may be missing.

However, running

```
npm search react-native
```

does list `react-native` as one of the matches, as I was expected.

What is it that I am missing? Am I misinterpreting something in the help page?

---

**Update**: Here's the output obtained from running each of the aforementioned command-line:

#### `npm search react`

```
$ npm search react
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORDS
react                     | React is a…          | =acdlite…       | 2020-03-19 | 16.13.1  | react   
react-select              | A Select control…    | =brianvaughn…   | 2020-03-22 | 3.1.0    | combobox form input multiselect react react-component select ui
react-dom                 | React package for…   | =acdlite…       | 2020-03-19 | 16.13.1  | react
react-draggable           | React draggable…     | =mzabriskie…    | 2020-04-12 | 4.3.1    | react draggable react-component
react-redux               | Official React…      | =gaearon…       | 2020-02-18 | 7.2.0    | react reactjs redux
react-popper              | Official library to… | =fezvrasta…     | 2020-04-11 | 2.2.2    | react react-popper popperjs component drop tooltip popover
eslint-plugin-react       | React specific…      | =ljharb…        | 2020-03-06 | 7.19.0   | eslint eslint-plugin eslintplugin react
prop-types                | Runtime type…        | =acdlite…       | 2019-02-13 | 15.7.2   | react
react-dropzone            | Simple HTML5…        | =okonet…        | 2020-04-26 | 11.0.1   | react-component react drag drop upload
react-color               | A Collection of…     | =case           | 2020-01-08 | 2.18.0   | react color picker react-component colorpicker picker sketch chrome photoshop material design popup
react-docgen              | A CLI and toolkit…   | =danez =fb      | 2020-02-26 | 5.3.0    | react documentation-generation
react-scripts             | Configuration and…   | =fb =gaearon…   | 2020-03-21 | 3.4.1    | 
hoist-non-react-statics   | Copies non-react…    | =mridgway       | 2020-01-22 | 3.3.2    | react
rc-util                   | Common Utils For…    | =afc163…        | 2020-04-25 | 4.20.5   | react util
react-table               | Hooks for building…  | =tannerlinsley… | 2020-04-02 | 7.0.4    | react table react-table datagrid
mobx-react                | React bindings for…  | =andykog…       | 2020-04-08 | 6.2.2    | mobx mobservable react-component react reactjs reactive
react-ace                 | A react component…   | =securingsinci… | 2020-03-14 | 8.1.0    | ace ace editor react-component react
babel-preset-react-app    | Babel preset used…   | =fb =gaearon…   | 2020-03-21 | 9.1.2    | 
react-transition-group    | A react component…   | =monastic.panic | 2019-09-05 | 4.3.0    | react transition addons transition-group animation css transitions
@babel/preset-react       | Babel preset for…    | =nicolo-ribaudo… | 2020-03-24 | 7.9.4    |
```

#### `npm search react-native`

```
$ npm search react-native
NAME                      | DESCRIPTION          | AUTHOR          | DATE       | VERSION  | KEYWORDS
react-native              | A framework for…     | =cpojer =fb…    | 2020-04-08 | 0.62.2   |         
react-native-svg          | SVG library for…     | =brentvatne…    | 2020-04-09 | 12.1.0   | react-component react-native ios android SVG ART VML gradient
css-to-react-native       | Convert CSS text to… | =jacobp100…     | 2019-10-10 | 3.0.0    | styled-components React ReactNative styles CSS
react-native-device-info  | Get device…          | =gantman…       | 2020-04-23 | 5.5.6    | react-component react-native ios android windows device events cocoapod
react-native-elements     | React Native…        | =dabit3…        | 2019-10-29 | 1.2.7    | react-native reactjs reactnative bootstrap
react-native-image-picker | A React Native…      | =haitaoli…      | 2020-02-26 | 2.3.1    | react-native react-native-image-picker react native image picker
@react-native-community/n | React Native…        | =mattoakes…     | 2020-04-22 | 5.8.0    | react-native react native netinfo networking network info
etinfo                    |                      |                 |            |          |                                                          
react-test-renderer       | React package for…   | =acdlite…       | 2020-03-19 | 16.13.1  | react react-native react-testing
react-with-styles         | [![Build…            | =etienne_tripi… | 2019-10-21 | 4.1.0    | react css styles aphrodite radium inline styles react native
react-native-calendars    | React Native…        | =tautvilas…     | 2020-04-02 | 1.265.0  | 
@react-navigation/native  | React Native…        | =brentvatne…    | 2020-04-27 | 5.1.7    | react-native react-navigation ios android
cross-fetch               | Universal WHATWG…    | =lquixada       | 2019-06-08 | 3.0.4    | fetch isomorphic universal node react native browser ponyfill whatwg xhr ajax
react-native-reanimated   | More powerful…       | =kmag           | 2020-04-07 | 1.8.0    | 
react-navigation          | Routing and…         | =brentvatne…    | 2020-04-22 | 4.3.8    | 
@sentry/react-native      | Official Sentry SDK… | =benvinegar…    | 2020-04-08 | 1.3.7    | react-native sentry crashreporting ios
@react-native-community/d | DateTimePicker…      | =eliwhite…      | 2020-04-09 | 2.3.2    | react-native-component react-native ios android datepicker timepicker datetime
atetimepicker             |                      |                 |            |          |                                                                               
@react-native-community/g | React Native…        | =mattoakes…     | 2019-08-18 | 2.0.2    | react-native geolocation location
eolocation                |                      |                 |            |          |                                  
react-content-loader      | SVG-Powered…         | =danilowoz      | 2020-04-08 | 5.0.4    | react react-native skeleton placeholder loader loading content svg
react-native-masked-text  | Text and TextInput…  | =benhurott      | 2019-08-13 | 1.13.0   | mask text textinput react-native custom money
react-navigation-stack    | Stack navigator…     | =brentvatne…    | 2020-04-22 | 2.3.13   | react-native-component react-component react-native ios android stack
```